# ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyinstaller Failed to build pyinstaller

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I need help.

Error while installing pyinstaller using pip `pip install pyinstaller`. I'm trying to install pyinstaller but each time I'm getting the same error.

ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyinstaller
Failed to build pyinstaller
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyinstaller which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue but I used `pip install pyinstaller==3.6` and it worked without any issues.
From: https://github.com/pydata/bottleneck/issues/343