# How to convert .py to .exe on MacOS

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am new to programming but previously considered myself above average in computer literacy. This issue is beginning to open my eyes to how little I know... Now to the issue.

I have downloaded IDLE to create some .py files and have been able to run them through this program. I would like to be able to convert them to a usable format and assume the .exe is the best format to accomplish this. I have tried to download pyinstaller to do this, but get the error ""Error: Building wheels requires the 'wheel' package. Please `pip install wheel` then try again." I do not understand what this is telling me to do.
I am running MacOS Monterey 12.5 if that is relevant.

Also: why is there not a website to convert these files like there is for PDFs or other documents? I would have thought there would be a simpler way to convert these files.

Comment: MacOS like all Linux/Unix variants don't use the `.exe` extension for binary executables, that's only used in Windows. You don't need to convert a Python script to binary in MacOS and almost all Linux/Unix distros as Python is part of the distro. You can execute them just like any other script. Finally, the error has nothing to do with executing the script. It tells you *exactly* what's wrong and what command to use to fix it. It says your script needs the `wheel` package, which can be installed with the `pip install wheel` command

Comment: Unless you want to distribute your code to others to run without them needing to know how to run it via `python` (or installing dependencies), you don't need pyinstaller. As for your error message, please familiarize yourself with Python's tools, like [`pip`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/), which is also briefly covered by the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  *"You don't need to convert a Python script to binary in MacOS and almost all Linux/Unix distros as Python is part of the distro"* That's a pretty bold (not to say wrong) statement. Many distros still ship with Python 2.7 ( EOLed more than 2 years ago), and even then, it is recommended to not rely on/mess with the system interpreted. More other, you are likely to have dependencies, and instead of explaining to end-users how to install them/create a virtualenv it is suggested to ship the program bundled with the interpreter and dependencies as an executable.

Comment: `why is there not a website to convert these files like there is for PDFs or other documents`. A Python file isn't a document to be converted. It's a script to be executed. It can only be executed if it's marked as executable, just like any other shell script. This is a very basic question

Comment: Are you using the most updated version of pyinstaller? Try running `pyinstaller --hidden-import 'wheel' --onefile my_file.py`. This [tutorial](https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/) may be of help as well. Based off your comments, not sure if an .exe is needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't just convert py to exe from a website, because as @Panagiotis mentioned, a Python file isn't just a document that can be converted, it's a script.

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405736/error-failed-building-wheel-for-pyinstaller-failed-to-build-pyinstaller) before. Instead of running `pip install pyinstaller`, run `pip install pyinstaller==3.6` (basically downgrading). If this doesn't work, run `pip install pyinstaller --no-binary :all:` instead.

This should solve all your issues.

Comment: there's this - https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/ which is pretty close. I suppose you could create one using a python web app and hook it up, but it still relies on the pyinstaller library....  so it's not really considered a website that converts it, more of a website that just uses the library and puts up some graphics...

Comment: And what would you call websites that convert between documents/images formats? Not "websites that use a library and put up some graphics"? I don't see how this would be *any* different

Comment: The question @Thomas Hudson has asked is based on the pyinstaller library. So a "website" that just uses the pyinstaller library to generate an exe file is useless...

Comment: Why would a site that uses pyinstaller be any more useless than a site that uses ffmpeg? Actually, such a site will be very useful, as it will allow someone with no access to platform X to build and ship executable to said platform (since pyinstaller does not support cross platform builds)

Comment: Relax dude. The answer I'm giving is based on the OP's situation. If the OP's question was - "can a website that uses pyinstaller to convert .py to .exe" be made", my answer would be different.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's question. It is about your answer and comment saying such website would be "useless" and "impossible" where it is clearly neither of these.

Comment: If you want to discuss this further with me, please move this to a chat. I don't want to clog up the comments with this argument.